# Reading file from one up directory in python2.7

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I am trying to read file in a python script from one up level.
My file structure is as below:

```
code
 - scripts
     -myscript.py
 - .env
```

In .env I have my configs.

And I am trying to read this file in myscript.py

I did the below to read it:

```
  envfile = open("../.env", "r")
```

Now when I run this python script from the scripts directory it works fine

This works good:

```
cd /var/www/html/code/scripts
python myscript.py
```

But if I do:

```
cd
python /var/www/html/code/scripts/myscript.py
```

Doesn't work and gives IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../.env'

How can I make it to run if I pass the absolute or relative path in terminal?

Comment: whats the cd doing

Comment: youre running it from a different path, i.e the level up from your cwd is not the one with .env

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/):

- pathlib2 is the version for python 2.7
- [pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

```py
    from pathlib import Path

    path = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1].joinpath(".env")
    envfile = open(path)
```

Comment: Great for a python 3 question, maybe not as good for python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
p = os.path.realpath(__file__)
envfile = open('/'.join(p.split('/')[:-1])+'/../.env')
```

also works

Comment: Probably won't work on a Windows, but I suspect 99.9% of the people reading this won't care.  Olvin's approach seems like it would work on any platform (supported by Path).

Comment: What's OP?  Do I need to change my comment to say 100% of the people reading this won't care :) ?

Comment: original poster

Comment: Very strange solution. If you want to use `str.join` and cut part of path why to not do like this: `envfile = open('/'.join(p.split('/')[:-2] + ['.env']))`.

Comment: yes could do that slightly different method..why is it strange to cut the part of the path you need?

Comment: @DerekEden strange to add `/../.etc` instead of cut last part of path and add filename.

Comment: just replaced the .py file with the location of .env relative to the file